# How to find the installed location of a software with Registry using C#

Tags: c#, find, location, registry

I'm a beginner to Registry keys, and
I want to find out the installed location of AutoCAD software which have the higher version of it using C#. 
More than one AutoCAD may get installed on a computer(AutoCAD 2012, AutoCAD 2014, etc), I want to get higher version alone., (result will be path of AutoCAD 2014(acad.exe))

And also have to find out acCoreConsole.exe file isExist on the path found in previous result..

I can't browse through the location of Registry.,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.2\ACAD-D001:409\AcadLocation
```

I tried this code:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Autodesk\\AutoCAD", false).GetSubKeyNames();
```

But this leads to somewhere else:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Autodesk\\ADSKAssetLibrary
```

I don't know how to get the location of acad.exe., I'm using 64 bit machine.
Any help would be appreciateable., Please do the needful,
Thanks,

Comment: Please re-format your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is most likely running 32 bit, because it seems like you get autoredirected to WoW6432Node which is the default directory for 32 bit applications.

Try this code:

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(@"your path here", false);
```

I'm pretty sure you run a 32 bit app on a 64 bit machine, I've had this problem before as well

EDIT: Forgot to append the last part of your command, but you can just append it I guess

Comment: Hi, yes i'm running an 32 bit app from 64 bit machine., This code worked fine, I got the expected output, appreciate for that.! But my doubt is "we are getting the path from 64 bit" as you mentioned, so will it work for 32 bit machine..? or need to make any code changes..? Thanks.,

Comment: I also found out about this code only a while ago and was not able to see what happens on 32 bit machines so far, sorry.